# How to run CGI on Jboss?

Tags: apache, cgi

(Oh, its Jboss not Apache. wow)

I am learning CGI and wish to run a test cgi on Jboss web server as first step lol. I have searched a lot of resources online and tried a lot of ways, but it still be opened as a text file on browser.

More facts:
1 I put script in a directory, and open it on browser e.g. www.xxxx.com/staging/welcome.cgi. Able to open, but shows text not run as script.

2 Script is starting with #!/usr/bin/perl -wT. And I have confirmed my server can run Perl script,path /usr/bin/perl is also correct.

3 I have tried modified httpd.conf according to the tutorials found online

Comment: Please lol don't lol use lol in lol questions lol when lol you lol really lol aren't lol lolling.

Comment: I am wrong, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most probably to do with the fact that the directory your script is placed in doesn't not ExecCGI Option enabled.

Typically done with something like

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/somedir>
Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/cgi.html

By default Apache nominates certain directories you can place CGI scripts in.

Comment: The other options is a ScriptAlias, which makes the entire directory get treated as cgi scripts, regardless of file extension.

Comment: I have this ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/" in httpd.conf, and have place script under /var/www/cig-bin, but when I access www.xxxx.com/cgi-bin. I get "HTTP Status 404 - /cgi-bin" error. :(

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /cgi-bin

type Status report

message /cgi-bin

description The requested resource (/cgi-bin) is not available.
JBoss Web/2.1.3.GA

Comment: Are you using Apache or JBoss distribution?

Comment: Ohh. I am newbie. I think it use Jboss as web server! yeah,man. How to do it in Jobss?